# how to make upper and lower case searchable in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, search, angular-material

I have search bar in my angular project and I'm trying to make the search bar to allow both upper case and lower case at the same time but not really sure how to do so I will be really appreciate if I can get any suggestion or help.

Right now every letter must be lower case in order to get the search result.

I want the search bar to allow both Pascal Case and Camel Case. for example user can enter,

"New York" "new york" "New york" "NeW YorK"  and return the same result.

HTML

```
 <input class="input" matInput name="query" [formControl]="query" placeholder="Filter Workspace">
```

TS

```
query: FormControl = new FormControl();
searchText: string;


  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.query.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.death$))
      .subscribe((value: string) => {
        this.search(value);
      });

  }

  search(searchText: string){
    // reset
    if (!searchText || searchText.length == 0) {
      this.charts = this.workspace.charts;
    }
    // search
    else {
      this.charts = this.charts.filter(chart => chart.name.toLocaleUpperCase().indexOf(searchText) >= 0);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert both `searchText` and `chart.name` to lower case, like this :

```
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
chart.name..toLowerCase().indexOf(*//your searching code//*);
```

This way, both upper and lower case is searchable together.